# Cannot read response from GetAsync in HttpClient, I have strange signs instead of json

Tags: c#, httpcontent

I have simple get request using `HttpClient`:

```
response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
```

And in `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` I have strange signs, while in Fiddler I can see normaly json:

```
"�\b\0\0\0\0\0\0}�AO�0\f��K�Z�M�vC0!��:���%�Ȕ&i�T�i��p��,?����$�K����s��.��ӡ�H$\tY��L��P֠#��\0�
```

Comment: Have you looked at the traffic in Wireshark? My guess is that you're getting compressed data and `HttpClient` isn't decompressing it.

Comment: What is the `Content-Type` inside the header?

Comment: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 in header, but content of response is StreamContent

Comment: In Fiddler I can see json

Comment: Ok, now it works, I add  new HttpClient(
                     new HttpClientHandler
                     {
                         AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
                                                  | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
                     }); and it works